# Why does reduce give a StackOverflowError in Clojure?

Tags: recursion, clojure, stack-overflow, reduce

I'm trying to concatenate a Seq of Seqs.

I can do it with `apply concat`.

```
user=> (count (apply concat (repeat 3000 (repeat 3000 true))))
9000000
```

However, from my limited knowledge, I would assume that the use of `apply` forces the lazy Seq to be realised, and that doesn't seem right for very large inputs. I'd rather do this lazily if I can.

So I thought that using `reduce` would do the job.

```
user=> (count (reduce concat (repeat 3000 (repeat 3000 true))))
```

But this results in

```
StackOverflowError   clojure.lang.RT.seq (RT.java:484)
```

I'm surprised because I would have thought that the semantics of `reduce` would mean it was tail-call recursive.

Two questions:

- Is `apply` the best way to do this?
- Is `reduce` generally inappropriate for large inputs?

Answer (score 31):

### Use `apply`. When the function argument is lazy, so is `apply`.

Let's check that with a counting side effect on the underlying sub-sequences:

```
(def counter (atom 0))

(def ss (repeatedly 3000 
          (fn [] (repeatedly 3000 
            (fn [] (do (swap! counter inc) true))))))


(def foo (apply concat ss))

so.core=> @counter
0

so.core=> (dorun (take 1 foo))
nil

so.core=> @counter
1

so.core=> (dorun (take 3001 foo))
nil

so.core=> @counter
3001
```

---

### `reduce` with a large number of `concat`s overflows due to thunk composition

Lazy sequences, such as those produced by `concat` are implemented with thunks, delayed function calls. When you `concat` the result of a `concat` you have nested a thunk within another thunk. In your function, the nesting goes 3000 deep and thus the stack is overflowed as soon as the first item is requested and the 3000 nested thunks are unwound.

```
so.core=>  (def bar (reduce concat (repeat 3000 (repeat 3000 true))))
#'so.core/bar

so.core=> (first bar)
StackOverflowError   clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:49)
```

The [implementation of lazy-sequences](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LazySeq.java#L48) will in general unwind nested thunks trampoline style when `seq`ed and not blow the stack:

```
so.core=> (loop [lz [1], n 0] 
            (if (< n 3000) (recur (lazy-seq lz) (inc n)) lz))
(1)
```

However, if you call `seq` within the lazy-sequence on the unrealized portion while realizing it...

```
so.core=> (loop [lz [1], n 0] 
            (if (< n 3000) (recur (lazy-seq (seq lz)) (inc n)) lz))
StackOverflowError   so.core/eval1405/fn--1406 (form-init584039696026177116.clj:1)

so.core=> (pst 3000)
```

```
StackOverflowError
        so.core/eval1619/fn--1620 (form-init584039696026177116.clj:2)
        clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval (LazySeq.java:40)
        clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:49)
        clojure.lang.RT.seq (RT.java:484)
        clojure.core/seq (core.clj:133)
        so.core/eval1619/fn--1620 (form-init584039696026177116.clj:2)
        clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval (LazySeq.java:40)
        clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:49)
        clojure.lang.RT.seq (RT.java:484)
        clojure.core/seq (core.clj:133)
        ... (repeatedly)
```

Then you end up building `seq` stack frames. The implementation of `concat` is such. Examine the stack trace for your StackOverflowError with `concat` and you will see similar.

Comment: Awesome explanation.  I found many dupes of this question on SO and this is by far the most clear explanation with very specific example code.  Well done!

Comment: For a complement, see Stuart Sierra's Don'ts about Concat: "Don’t use lazy sequence operations in a non-lazy loop." in https://stuartsierra.com/2015/04/26/clojure-donts-concat

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest a way to avoid the problem.  The `reduce` function isn't the problem here; `concat` is.

Take a look at:
https://stuartsierra.com/2015/04/26/clojure-donts-concat

Instead of using `concat` use `into`

```
(count (reduce into (repeat 3000 (repeat 3000 true))))
9000000
```