# Clojure thunks: stack overflow with [0] but not '(0)?

Tags: clojure, stack-overflow, lazy-evaluation, thunk

Here's a snippet of code that gives me a `StackOverflowError` (boiled down from an actual example in my codebase):

```
( ->> (range 3000)
      (mapcat #(concat [0] (take 100 (repeat %))))
      (reduce (constantly nil))
      (count))
```

(Note: this code isn't designed to *do* anything other than demonstrate the problem or return zero.)

I can "rescue" it by any of the following steps:

1. Remove the `reduce` line
2. Change `[0]` to  `'(0)`
3. Add a `(take 100000000)` (or any integer) at any point between `mapcat` and `count`.

I'm basically baffled by this behavior (especially #2). I'd appreciate any input.

(I have a feeling this may be related to [Why does reduce give a StackOverflowError in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958907/why-does-reduce-give-a-stackoverflowerror-in-clojure), but I can't quite tell how -- so if it is related, I'd appreciate an explanation of why.)

Comment: Is it suppose to return 0?
Interestingly I don't get a stack overflow if I change it to this:

( ->> (range)
      (mapcat
       (fn [p]
         (concat [0] (take 100 (repeat nil)))))
      (take 3000)
      (reduce (constantly nil))
      (count))

Comment: Yes, it's "supposed to" return 0. (I mean, the code isn't really supposed to do anything other than demonstrate this behavior in the shortest way I could find.) The `count` is just in there to demonstrate that consuming the sequence itself doesn't cause an error. In your example, @firthh, you can change (take 3000) to (take 3000000) if you like, and it still works. You can also put the (take 3000) after the reduce step...

Comment: reduce is strict, and uses constant stack space - it is more likely the concat / mapcat calls stacking up unevaluated before being forced that are causing the issue

Comment: @noisesmith that's not really an explanation, though. Why does `count` succeed when I remove the `reduce`? And why does '(0) act differently? And why doesn't wrapping the concat (or mapcat) result in (doall) help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, `reduce` operates using a `loop`/`recur` construct and uses constant stack space. However, you've hit a nasty corner case caused by reducing over a sequence produced by providing `concat` with alternating chunked and non-chunked sequences (the vector `[0]` is chunked; the seq produced by `(take 100 (repeat %))` is non-chunked).

When the first argument to `concat` is a chunked sequence, then it will return a lazy sequence that will use `chunk-cons` to produce another chunked sequence. Otherwise, it will use `cons` to produce a non-chunked sequence.

Meanwhile, the implementation of `reduce` uses the `InternalReduce` protocol (defined in `clojure.core.protocols`) which provides an `internal-reduce` function for structures that can reduce themselves more efficiently than with the default first/next recursion. The `internal-reduce` implementation for chunked sequences uses chunk functions to consume the chunked items in a loop up until it's left with a non-chunked sequence, then calls `internal-reduce` on the remainder. The default `internal-reduce` implementation similarly uses `first`/`next` to consume items in a loop until the underlying seq type changes, then calls `internal-reduce` on the new seq type to dispatch to the appropriate optimized version. As you progress through the seq that `concat` produced, alternating between chunked and non-chunked sub-sequences, the `internal-reduce` calls pile up on the stack and eventually blow it.

A simpler illustration of this case is:

```
;; All chunked sub-seqs is OK
user> (reduce + (apply concat (take 10000 (repeat [1]))))
10000

;; All non-chunked sub-seqs is OK
user> (reduce + (apply concat (take 10000 (repeat '(1)))))
10000

;; Interleaved chunked and non-chunked sub-seqs blows the stack
user> (reduce + (apply concat (take 10000 (interleave (repeat [1]) (repeat '(1))))))
StackOverflowError   clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:60)
```

Examining the stack trace:

```
StackOverflowError 
    clojure.core/seq (core.clj:133)
    clojure.core/interleave/fn--4525 (core.clj:3901)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval (LazySeq.java:42)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:60)
    clojure.lang.RT.seq (RT.java:484)
    clojure.core/seq (core.clj:133)
    clojure.core/take/fn--4232 (core.clj:2554)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval (LazySeq.java:42)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:60)
    clojure.lang.Cons.next (Cons.java:39)
    clojure.lang.RT.next (RT.java:598)
    clojure.core/next (core.clj:64)
    clojure.core/concat/cat--3925/fn--3926 (core.clj:694)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval (LazySeq.java:42)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:60)
    clojure.lang.ChunkedCons.chunkedNext (ChunkedCons.java:59)
    clojure.core/chunk-next (core.clj:660)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn--6041 (protocols.clj:101)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn--6005/G--6000--6014 (protocols.clj:19)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn--6034 (protocols.clj:147)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn--6005/G--6000--6014 (protocols.clj:19)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn--6041 (protocols.clj:104)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn--6005/G--6000--6014 (protocols.clj:19)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn--6034 (protocols.clj:147)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn--6005/G--6000--6014 (protocols.clj:19)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn--6041 (protocols.clj:104)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn--6005/G--6000--6014 (protocols.clj:19)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn--6034 (protocols.clj:147)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn--6005/G--6000--6014 (protocols.clj:19)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn--6041 (protocols.clj:104)
```

As for your workarounds:

- Clearly, avoiding `reduce` prevents the problem altogether.
- Changing `[0]` to `'(0)` replaces the chunked sub-sequences with non-chunked ones, circumventing the optimization for chunked seqs in `internal-reduce` and allowing the reduction to happen in a single loop with constant stack space.
- Inserting `take` creates a new, non-chunked sequence, composed entirely of cons cells.

Comment: Yes, this is it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `mapcat`, which calls `concat`, which uses `cons`. `cons` on vectors is expensive (and probably consumes stack), while it's cheap for lists. That's why changing from vector to list "fixes" the problem.

Comment: Can you clarify why the failure only happens in the `reduce` step? If I remove `reduce`, why does `count` still work (which consumes the whole sequenece with no trouble)